# why Input field returned by a react component function goes out of focus on each key

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component

when I create a function to return a JSX input field in react, the cursor goes out of focus on each key, meaning i can enter one character and then I have to click on the input field again to enter another character, can someone explain whats going on and how i can prevent this or doing this in react is not advisable? my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function App(props) {
   const [value, setValue] = useState();

   const Show = () => {
     return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
        </div>
    )
  }



   return (
       <Show></Show>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've defined a component within a function.

Every time `App` re-renders, its really a new function call. This means `Show` is redefined. It's completely destroyed and re-created. The result is that every re-render, `<Show/>` is re-mounted. The input will lose focus on a component re-mount.

**Do not** declare components within other components. There is no benefit, only drawbacks.

Assuming your actual use-case does have a reason for separating the `input` from the rest of the return JSX, you could call it as a function instead of a component. Make the const lowercase, and instead of `<Show></Show>` return `show()`. The state variables will remain in scope, but it will no longer be a component, just a function that returns JSX.

Otherwise I would recommend putting it outside the `App` function and passing in your state value and updater through props.

Comment: thank you, whats the best way to separate the conditionals? point of this was to have Show function return something and else return soemthing else and didnt want to do logic in the return statement? create another component in a different js file?

Comment: JSX allows ternary operators. So it could be something like `{condition ? <input/> : <button/>}`. Or you could use the first alternative method I listed and add the `if` within the `show()` function.